# Help needed in RESTful design

Tags: rest

I am learning to develop some RESTful code, and I faltered at the first step :(

This project is for a mobile platform. The user is presented a login form, which if he fills correctly, is shown a page where half of the screen shows a list of books he has bought, and the other half shows the list of books recently added to the book store (my server).

1. I am using names like "LoginService", "SearchBookService", "SelectBookService" in my project....I am just trying to convert a verb to a noun by appending the word "service" to all verbs. Is it OK ?
2. Since I need to give the output of two services ("MyBooksService" & "RecentlyAddedService") after he calls just one service ("LoginService"), I am wondering how will I send two different sets of outputs....and whether the redirection from the "LoginService" to the "MyBooksService" & "RecentlyAddedService" should be internal (on the server), or on the client side ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) It's important to choose good names for your REST resources.  I'd suggest your resource names (URIs) look something like:

```
.../books/user/bob
.../books/recentlyadded
```

The code implementing these resources return representations that are lists of books (where each book's representation might have a title, an author, an ISBN number, an image URI, and so on).  You might name these modules the UserBooksResource and the RecentlyAddedBooksResource perhaps.  The names shouldn't matter that much, since they can be changed without affecting your actual REST API (ie, the URI resource names, the representations, the HTTP operation verbs, etc.)

(2) Security can be done in several ways.  If you're in the Java world, for instance, check out the Spring Framework's security.  This interposes the login processing above the servlets producing the representations.  Or consider using the Restlet framework, which has great REST support and includes the notion of Guards that issue security challenges before a request gets to your REST resource code.  Restlet also provides clean ways to generate different kinds of representations for the same resource (eg, XML plus JSON plus XHTML depending on what the client asks for in its Accept header).

If you can, do study Richardson and Ruby's RESTFul Web Services (O'Reilly), a very clear explanation of how to implement REST services.

Comment: Is his second question really about security or about where he should be stitching together the data retrieved from two separate service calls to get the data to populate two difference sections of the app?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using names like "LoginService",
>   "SearchBookService",
>   "SelectBookService" in my project....I
>   am just trying to convert a verb to a
>   noun by appending the word "service"
>   to all verbs. Is it OK ?

Why not? Important is that your naming makes sense and is consistent through out the whole project. That way you or any other person working on the code at a later stage won't have issues to understand what is requested.

> Since I need to give the output of two
>   services ("MyBooksService" &
>   "RecentlyAddedService") after he calls
>   just one service ("LoginService"), I
>   am wondering how will I send two
>   different sets of outputs....and
>   whether the redirection from the
>   "LoginService" to the "MyBooksService"
>   & "RecentlyAddedService" should be
>   internal (on the server), or on the
>   client side ?

I would execute all API requests on the server side. If you do a webbased application for mobile phone, you might have to deal with other phones than iphone or android powered phones. Not all of them support javascript or have javascript activate by default. Be careful here!

Hope a understood your questions correctly, if not please ask again.